# Storing the data inside an array as rosbag

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way I can store data in my array (inside a c++ program) as rosbag? Just like I can store it as txt or csv file. I know we can store data being published over a ros topic as rosbag but I am wondering if I can do that without publishing the data on rostopic.

regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/170876/storing-the-data-inside-an-array-as-rosbag/) by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2014-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbag has a C++ API that you can use directly in your code: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API

But I think everything you store will need to be ROS messages. So you'd need to define a ROS message type for your array, e.g. a file called "Foo.msg" which contains "float64[] some_array". Then you need to get catkin to generate code wrappers for that message.

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2014-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1